Vue Webpack app does not recognize style classes
I am making a web application in vuejs and webpack but, webpack won't load the style classes declared in my component (style components).
Apparently, the problem could be that the style-loader is misconfigured because it is a new project
In case this is problem, would anyone be able to take a look at it?
Webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const src  = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const IS_PRODUCTION = argv.mode === 'production';

    const config = {
        entry: './src/main.js',
        output: {
            path: dist,
            filename: '[name]-[contenthash].js'
        },

        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@": src
            }
        },
        mode: argv.mode,
        devServer: {
            static: dist
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: 'index.html',
                template: './public/index.html'
            }),
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    IS_PRODUCTION ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: "[local]--[hash:base64:6]",
                            },
                            esModule: false                         
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webm|mp4|svg)$/,
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    outputPath: "assets"
                }
            }]
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                // extend default plugins
                `...`,
                // HTML and JS are minified by default if config.mode === production.
                // But for CSS we need to add this:
                new CssMinimizerPlugin()
            ],
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    commons: {
                      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                      name: 'node_modules',
                      chunks: 'all',
                    },
                },
            },
        }
    };

    return config;
}

My problem is that it compiles and recognizes the main.css but not the style classes.

Why do you start a new project in Webpack and not Vite? Do you have specific needs regarding Webpack?

Here is what happens when you expose the config of the default Vue3 Webpack config CLI.
StackOverflow limits the amount of characters, here is one of my public gists with a very long config.
Meanwhile
I do not recommend trying to look for any Webpack configs regarding Vue3 because the CLI listed above is outdated as said on the given page. Here are some details about the old CLI, do not use it.
You should be using Vite, as said in the docs with the current up-to-date CLI.
It will be faster, easier to configure, and far more people to help you with the config in case you need some help. On the other hand, nobody wants to deal with the long config of Webpack so getting some help on that subject will be quite difficult.
